# MySQL return set fields

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, datatables

Hi I have a MySQL query as follows that is called from c# and used for server side Paging of jQuery DataTables

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT (@rn := @rn + 1) AS RowNumber,item_id,description
FROM
    (SELECT (SELECT count(item.item_id)
            FROM
                item) AS TotalRows
        , ( SELECT  count(item_id) FROM item  ) AS TotalDisplayRows ,item_id,description
    FROM
        item  ) RawResults
    ) Results 
    WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN 1 AND 10
```

This returns RowNumber, item_id, description

I also need to return TotalRows and TotalDisplayRows. Cant figure out how to do it. Any help please. Thanks

This is the query working in SQL

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY  NO  asc) AS RowNumber , *
    FROM
        (SELECT (SELECT count(item.item_id)
                FROM
                    item) AS TotalRows 
            , ( SELECT  count(item_id) FROM iq_item  ) AS TotalDisplayRows ,*
        FROM
            item ) RawResults) Results WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN 1 AND 10
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with mysql but I don't think you can get your paged results AND the filtered rowcount AND the total rowcount in a single query.

Answer (score 0):

Decrypting your query is quite complicated...

Is it what you want?

```
// returns first 10 results
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS item_id, description FROM item LIMIT 0, 10;
// get total number of elements
SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS TotalRows;
```

You row number has to be calculated with your pagination indices and your returned row position, while the TotalDisplayRows is the number of returned rows if I understand what you're intending to do

Comment: ye its quite complicated. ITs to worj with jQuery datatables server side pagiing. Rowumber is the id of the row, totalrows is the total rows from the master query select * from item. TotalDisplayrows is the total rows brought back this time i pass in pagestart pageend in this case 1 and 10 .... i added the query in SQL working above, because it can use an over statement it works well

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @markpsmith i got it sorted using seperate queries to get the total rows and total display rows.

Total Rows

```
SELECT count(item.item_id) FROM item @where
```

Total Display Rows

```
SELECT count(item.item_id) FROM item @filteredwhere
```

Main Query

```
SET @rn := 0;
SELECT * FROM (SELECT (@rn := @rn + 1) AS RowNumber,item_id,description
FROM
    (SELECT (SELECT count(item.item_id)
            FROM
                item) AS TotalRows
        , ( SELECT  count(item_id) FROM item @where) AS TotalDisplayRows ,item_id,description
    FROM
        item where item_id @filteredwhere  ) RawResults
    ) Results 
    WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN 1 AND 50;
```